# Neo4j unmanaged extension: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm experiencing the "classic" `The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes` error from `HelloWorldResource.java`

I've followed [Unmanaged Extensions](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.1/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) instructions:

- Added JAR file in *plugins* directory
- Set org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=**org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged=/examples/unmanaged**

And here's the code:

```
package org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged;

import ...

@Path( "/helloworld" )
public class HelloWorldResource {

    //private final GraphDatabaseService database;

    //public HelloWorldResource( @Context GraphDatabaseService database )
    //{
    //    this.database = database;
    //}

    @GET
    @Produces( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN )
    @Path( "/{nodeId}" )
    public Response hello( @PathParam( "nodeId" ) long nodeId )
    {
        // Do stuff with the database
        return Response.status( Status.OK ).entity(
                ("Hello World, nodeId=" + nodeId).getBytes( Charset.forName("UTF-8") ) ).build();
    }
}
```

I'm using Windows 8.1 and ENTERPRISE 2.2.0_M02, when running `bin\Neo4j.bat` I get the error.

```
C:\Users\user\Dropbox\MyDBs\neo4j\dbmusicovery3>bin\Neo4j.bat
    2015-06-15 23:14:58.889+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on 120000
    2015-06-15 23:15:05.397+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully started database
    2015-06-15 23:15:05.477+0000 INFO  [API] Starting HTTP on port :7474 with 4 threads available
    2015-06-15 23:15:05.724+0000 INFO  [API] Enabling HTTPS on port :7473
    2015-06-15 23:15:05.856+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted REST API at: /db/manage
    2015-06-15 23:15:05.875+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted unmanaged extension [neo4j.unmanaged] at [/examples/unmanaged]
    01:15:05.894 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @8256ms
    2015-06-15 23:15:05.956+0000 INFO  [API] Mounting static content at [/webadmin] from [webadmin-html]
    2015-06-15 23:15:06.015+0000 INFO  [API] Mounting static content at [/browser] from [browser]
    01:15:06.019 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.2.1.v20140609
    01:15:06.065 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.h.MovedContextHandler@3827eac9{/,null,AVAILABLE}
    01:15:06.206 [main] INFO  o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor - NO JSP Support for /webadmin, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
    01:15:06.226 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2aea41c2{/webadmin,jar:file:/C:/Users/user/Dropbox/MyDBs/neo4j/dbmusico
    very3/system/lib/neo4j-server-2.2.0-M02-static-web.jar!/webadmin-html,AVAILABLE}
    01:15:06.764 [main] WARN  /examples/unmanaged - unavailable
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
...
... FAILED o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1f7bd4dd{/examples/unmanaged,null,STARTING}:
...
```

Some logs:

```
juin 16, 2015 9:51:26 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFOS: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  neo4j.unmanaged
juin 16, 2015 9:51:26 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFOS: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.18.1 02/19/2014 03:28 AM'
juin 16, 2015 9:51:26 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules <init>
GRAVE: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
```

Quick jar of the JAR:

```
C:\...\plugins>jar tf myapp.jar
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
pom.xml
.project
org/neo4j/examples/server/unmanaged/AppTest.class
org/neo4j/examples/server/unmanaged/HelloWorldResource.class
target/test-classes/org/neo4j/examples/server/unmanaged/AppTest.class
.classpath
```

Comment: I've got the same problem. Have you resolved this yet?

Comment: Having the same issue ... Anybody figured out how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with the JAR file. I've tested [dmontag/neo4j-unmanaged-extension-template](https://github.com/dmontag/neo4j-unmanaged-extension-template.git) on both localhost:7474 (Windows 8.1) and AWS EC2 (Ubuntu 14.04) and it works fine. Consequently, I'll try to stick to this template. By the way, it's not "curl http://localhost:7474/example/helloworld" it's "curl http://localhost:7474/example/**service**/helloworld" instead, and don't forget Authorization headers, `curl -H "Authorization: Basic <Base64 of user:password>"` or `curl -u ":<token>"`